# changed name of uploaded file in codeigniter to random string

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

I upload audio file with Codeigniter. But name of File chaned to long random string and number.

sample Array of output Codeigniter(my file => ball.wav):

```
Array ( [upload_data] => Array ( [file_name] => 5371ab05c91db790df31c6cc1e1ed0da.wav [file_type] => audio/x-wav
```

Comment: probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/12659054/2275490

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [CodeIgniter documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html):

```
$config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
```

> If set to TRUE the file name will be converted to a random encrypted
>   string. This can be useful if you would like the file saved with a
>   name that can not be discerned by the person uploading it.

```
$config['file_name'] = 'Somename';
```

> If set CodeIgniter will rename the uploaded file to this name. The
>   extension provided in the file name must also be an allowed file type.
>   If no extension is provided in the original file_name will be used.

This should be put before you run upload:

```
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```